# DDD, modularizing the application and domain layers without breaking the DIP

Tags: domain-driven-design, patterns-and-practices, solid, layers, architectural-patterns

Quoting [DDD theory](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/architecture.html):

> The application layer is thin in terms of domain logic - it merely
>   coordinates the domain layer objects to perform the actual work.

When it comes to modularization, and assuming that the module containing the domain entities and the interfaces of the domain services belongs to the domain layer, the application layer depends on the domain layer, which breaks the [dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

> The implementation of the high-level component's interface by the low
>   level component requires that the low-level component package depend
>   upon the high-level component for compilation, thus inverting the
>   conventional dependency relationship.

What am I missing?

I add an UML diagram to clarify the problem I see.
[image]

- The Persistence Layer depends upon an abstration in the Domain Layer
  -> DIP ok!
- The Application Layer depends upon an abstraction in the Domain Layer -> Does this break the DIP?

Comment: Would you please explain what "Application Service" means? At least what definition are you using in this context?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268699/domain-driven-design-domain-service-application-service

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't break DIP because Domain is the highest level, higher than Application, and doesn't have a dependency on it. The reverse (Domain depending on Application) would break DIP.

Also, the "should depend on abstraction" part of DIP doesn't necessarily apply here, because domain entities can't be abstracted -- they are already a pure conceptual model of your domain. The only exception may be Domain Services, because you could place an interface in front of those.

As a side note, you generally don't need to leverage dependency inversion inside the Domain model itself, because

- Domain entities have few to no collaborators
- The ones they have are well identified (ubiquitous language) and often not polymorphic in nature
- Domain resides entirely in memory with no external communication (3d party framework, network, disk, etc.) involved, so it can be tested with fast integration tests without needing mocks.

Comment: Honestly, IMHO this answer misses the point. If an Application layer depends on a Domain layer *directly*, this can be a violation of the DIP as well as the other way round. The key point is that the Application layer does only depend on *interfaces* of the Domain Layer classes, not on the domain layer classes directly.

Comment: Disagree. Domain Entities are concrete, rarely abstract. Your repositories don't return abstractions. Entities are what the Application layer services manipulate in a typical DDD architecture, yet they don't violate SRP.

Comment: How can domain be higher level than application? "The application layer is thin in terms of domain logic - it merely coordinates the domain layer objects to perform the actual work."

This means that the application layer is a consumer of the services provided by the domain layer, and that's what I understand as being a higher level.

Comment: I also agree that doesn't make sense to have abstractions for the domain entitites. And since both application and data access layers (as you pointed out, a repository implementation needs to return a real entity) need to use domain entities, then both depend upon the domain layer and both break the DIP.

Comment: @diegomtassis: you are fully correct (at least, to my understanding of what an application layer is). What guillaume IMHO *really* wants to say is that in a context of lightweight domain entities applying DI to the application layer is often just not useful. For example, to unit test the application layer one can utilize domain entities directly, assumed there is a possibility to create them without a database (probably through a mock repository). I still will not upvote this answer as long as it starts with this first, IMHO wrong, sentence.

Comment: @diegomtassis The Domain is higher level **and doesn't have a dependency on Application** (edited my answer to reflect that). You are complicating yourself by trying to apply a principle where it doesn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: @diegomtassis Domain is higher than application because "It is the high level modules that contain the important policy decisions and business models of an application." (original DIP article, page 6) http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf

Comment: @guillaume31 I didn't say that domain depends on application, but the opposite.

Comment: If application is lower level than domain.. how can application consume domain? The definition of application layer says that it coordinates the domain layer objects to perform the actual work.

Comment: @diegomtassis Level doesn't say anything about who consumes who. Coordinating is not a sign of higher level, IMO, but I admit this is debatable. DIP is not rocket science anyway, you should apply it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

The Dependency Inversion Principle has one major exception: At some point you must do something concrete. An example is in order.

Let's say you've got a Blogging application. You've got two tables in the database, and two domain models, say `Blog` and `Post`. Let's also say you are working with an MVC framework like ASP.NET MVC, Ruby on Rails, etc.

Now, let's say you've got another class called `BlogPostsController` implementing the basic CRUD operations for blog posts.

The framework implements the Dependency Inversion Principle by not hard coding the following lines *anywhere* in its code base:

```
new BlogPostsController();
```

The framework looks at the incoming URL and constructs the name of the controller class dynamically. The framework doesn't have a hard dependency on your `BlogPostsController` class.

Now, let's look at the controller. Inside your controller you see `new Post()` peppered all over. This is *not* a violation of the Dependency Inversion Principle because at some point you, as a programmer, need to actually save a blog post to the database.

The Dependency Inversion Principle is mainly aimed at dependencies that aren't laser focused on the basic intent of a class, for instance creating a new "controller" in an MVC framework. You don't want a hard coded `switch` or `if` statement in order to do that. Authentication is another area where DIP is important because your `BlogPostsController` class shouldn't care how browser cookies are handled, or if the user logs in using a custom login page wired to a Database, or using Windows authentication or plain text authentication in the browser wired to LDAP behind the scenes.

Comment: The DIP says that high level modules shouldn't depend on low level modules, both should depend upon abstractions. That´s the original formulation by Robert Martin. Then, some versions say that the abstractions belong to the upper level, and that's the problem I see.

When it comes to Domain layer - Data Access layer everything is ok, because the Repositoy interfaces belong to the Domain layer and the implementation to the Data access layer, but when it comes to application layer - domain layer is different, the domain entities belong to the Domain layer.

Answer (score 1):

The DI means your Application layer shall not depend directly on the Domain Service classes, but on abstract interfaces of those service classes (actually, your diagram is already showing this). The only thing which is debatable is if those interfaces should be placed in the Domain Layer. You better place them outside, in a "Service Interface" layer, so they can be referenced from the Application layer as well as from the Domain layer. This way, you have no direct dependendencies between Application layer and Domain layer, in none of the two possible directions.

Of course, as Greg has already pointed out, somewhere in your application you have to wire everything together and actually create non-abstract instances of your Domain Service classes. Either you use a DI framework for this purpose, or you do this manually in a kind of "infrastructure" part of your program, outside of any of the classic "layers". Neither a DI framework, nor a manual start-up infrastructure is relevant in the sense of the DIP.

Comment: Exactly, the original formulation of the DIP by Uncle Bob says "High level modules should not depend upon low level modules. Both should depend upon abstractions.". Then, in small type, it also says "Each of the lower level layers are represented by an abstract class. The actual layers are then derived from these abstract classes. Each of the higher level classes uses the next lowest layer through the abstract inter-face. Thus, none of the layers depends upon any ofthe other layers.". So I assume the abstractions are not considered part of any layer.

Comment: We can interpret the DIP that way, but still contradicts what some people think: "Keep the abstraction closer to the classes that depend upon it and further from the classes that extend or implement it" (Java Application Architecture: Modularity patterns with Examples using OSGi, Kirk Knoernschild, page 238).

Comment: @diegomtassis The point of DIP is to minimize dependencies. What matters is that the interface is separate from the implementation so you can develop the layers independently. Think of C code for example - the headers (interfaces) for a library can be distributed separately and you can compile your part of the code without having the library's implementation on hand. It doesn't matter where you put the library's interface in your *mental model* of the code as long as it can be *packaged* separately. Where you draw the line between what's "application" and "domain" code is subjective.

Comment: @diegomtassis: where do you see a contradiction? What I wrote above means "keep the abstraction (Service Interface) further from the classes that implement it (Domain Layer)" by putting it in a separate layer (or maybe we should not say layer, but component). I don't see a contradiction to your cite.

Comment: No, not you. The "Thus, none of the layers depends upon any ofthe other layers" contradicts the "Keep the abstraction closer to the classes that depend upon it and further from the classes that extend or implement it". The first says that doesn't matter where the abstractions are, the second says they have to be close to the consumer.

Comment: And my diagram is not 100% realistic, because you can expose the domain services via interfaces... but the domain entities? That's odd. And what happens if an application service has to create an entity instance?

Comment: @diegomtassis What does "closeness" or "distance" mean in relation to classes and interfaces? That Knoernschild quote makes no sense out of context, and without any rationale to back it up I don't see why it should be regarded as equally important as following DIP.

Comment: @DocBrown Domain Services are rare. I'd say they represent 20% at most of all externally accessible objects living in your Domain Layer in a typical DDD system.

Comment: @Docbrown Plus, if you move your Domain Services interfaces to an additional layer, you'll always have a top-level layer referenced by all others. Exactly like when the Domain layer is topmost.

Comment: @guillaume31: I don't see what your first comment has to do with the actual question. And the second comment misses the point that  this "top-most" layer is only a layer of abstractions (whilst the Domain layer is exactly the opposite, it is a layer of implementations). In the result, the application layer does not rely on the domain layer any more, it relies on an abstraction of the domain layer, exactly what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @DocBrown My first comment was precisely to say that the Domain is a layer of purely concrete classes (well, at least 80% of it). You're basing your answer on the 20% that is not representative of what the Domain is. There's no point in abstracting a BlogPost, an OrderLine or a CargoShippingRoute.

Comment: @guillaume31: well, in this case I interpret your own answer above as "it breaks the DPI, but it does not matter, because the DI is not useful here". That is quite a valid point of view (though I think your wording above a little confusing).

Comment: @DocBrown You're right. I edited my answer to better reflect that. I think it still respects the spirit of DIP though.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot yet comment so here we go: Your misunderstanding becomes very obvious if you look at graphs of a "hexagonal architecture". Essentially DDD just wants all your sourcecode dependencies to point "inwards" into your application core, into your domain.

The architecture you layed out does not violate this principle. You merely use the DIP to topple the layers persistence and application, avoiding for the dependency to point "downwards".